# AngularJS and cordova : web app working but not on cordova : Failed to instantiate module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'm tryin to make a mobile app based a web application (simple todolist), using cordova. It works on ripple but on the phone, the angularJS doesnt seem to activate.

in android studio, i get this in console :

E/Web Console﹕ Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module todoList due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'todoList' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

here is the index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" ng-app="todoList">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <title>Pense-bête</title>        
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/todoList.js"></script>

    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Pense-bête</h1>
        </header>
        <section ng-controller="todoCtrl">
            <form id="todo-form" ng-submit="addTodo()">
                <input id="new-todo" placeholder="Que voulez-vous acheter ?" ng-model="newTodo" />
            </form>
            <article ng-show="todos.length">
                <ul id="todo-list">
                    <li ng-repeat="todo in todos" ng-class="{completed: todo.completed}">
                        <div class="view">
                            <input class="mark" type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.completed" />
                            <span>{{todo.title}}</span>
                            <span class="close" ng-click="removeTodo(todo)">x</span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div>
                    <input id="mark-all" type="checkbox" ng-model="allChecked" ng-click="markAll(allChecked)" />
                    <label class="btn btn-info" for="mark-all">Tout cocher</label>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="clearCompletedTodos()">Supprimer les tâches cochées</button>

                    <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" ng-click="savedata()">Synchroniser ma liste</button>
                </div>
                        <div class="view" ng-model="result">
                            <span>{{result}}</span>
                        </div>
            </article>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the todolist.js :

// js/todoList.js

```
'use strict';


/**

/**
 * Déclaration du module todoList
 */
var todoList = angular.module('todoList',[]);


/**
 * Contrôleur de l'application "Todo List" décrite dans le chapitre "La logique d'AngularJS".
 */
todoList.controller('todoCtrl', ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {

        // Pour manipuler plus simplement les todos au sein du contrôleur
        // On initialise les todos avec un tableau vide : []
        var todos = $scope.todos = [];

        // Ajouter un todo
        $scope.addTodo = function () {
            // .trim() permet de supprimer les espaces inutiles
            // en début et fin d'une chaîne de caractères
            var newTodo = $scope.newTodo.trim();
            if (!newTodo.length) {
                // éviter les todos vides
                return;
            }
            todos.push({
                // on ajoute le todo au tableau des todos
                title: newTodo,
                completed: false
            });
            // Réinitialisation de la variable newTodo
            $scope.newTodo = '';
        };

        // Enlever un todo
        $scope.removeTodo = function (todo) {
            todos.splice(todos.indexOf(todo), 1);
        };

        // Cocher / Décocher tous les todos
        $scope.markAll = function (completed) {
            todos.forEach(function (todo) {
                todo.completed = !completed;
            });
        };

        // Enlever tous les todos cochés
        $scope.clearCompletedTodos = function () {
            $scope.todos = todos = todos.filter(function (todo) {
                return !todo.completed;
            });
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: You can't run PHP inside a cordova app, you should put your todolist_updater.php in a PHP server

Comment: ok but :
1/ This should avoid my user interface to work ?
2/ How i call such service ?

Comment: i put the old code with no php reference, still has the pb

Comment: do you see any error message on the logcat console?

Comment: How can i see that ?

Comment: Are you certain todoList.js is loading? Can you check your sources

Comment: In Web mode yes, it works perfectly, but how do i see this in mobile ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug your website on the phone, you can use safari mobile inspector to get access to the console and start logging messages, as well as see any errors that may be popping up.  You can find out how to do this here:
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787

Comment: Thank you but i don't have any iphone, using samsung s4 mini android 4.2.2.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging @Nightf here is an Android version

Comment: i manage to debug it on Android studio : i have the following erreor message :
E/Web Console﹕ Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module todoList due to:
    Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'todoList' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: i tried it, but it doesnt allow me to view the cordova app.

Answer (score 0):

OMG, i had todoList.js and not todolist.js in my src..

At least, it allowed me to discover remote debugging with chrome.

thanks !